# Endpoint Rest com Jersey não exibe resultado esperado

Tags: java, java-ee, jersey

Criei um projeto JavaEE diretamente no Intellij e adicionei as dependências do JavaEE 8 via maven.
A estrutura do projeto está nesse [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAq0V.jpg).

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
</web-app>
```

beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

JerseyConfig:

```
@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class JerseyConfig extends Application {

//    @Override
//    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses()
//    {
//        Set<Class<?>> yourResources = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
//        yourResources.add(MySimpleRest.class);
//        return yourResources;
//    }


}
```

MySimpleRest :

```
@Path("/info")
public class MySimpleRest {

    @GET
    public String get(){
        return "Hello Word";
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>JavaEE</groupId>
    <artifactId>JavaEE</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <!--<packaging>war</packaging>-->

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Estou tentando acessar a url `http://localhost:9090/resources/info` e me retorna 404.
O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que o problema esteja na classe de inicalização, proponho as seguintes mudanças:

Primeiramente adicione estas dependências (do Jersey) no seu `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.27</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Isso é necessário se for usar a ultima versao do Jersey -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
```

JerseyConfig:

```
@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        //Scaneia Dinamicamente pelos Controllers (classes com @Path)
        packages("br.com.javaee.controllers");
    }
}
```

MySimpleRest :

```
@Path("/info")
public class MySimpleRest {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response get() {
        return Response.ok("Hello Word").build();
    }
}
```

---

Segundo [esse link](https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-404-ao-acessar-ws-pelo-wildfly-29490) e [esse link](https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-404-not-found-wildfly-10-versao-que-estou-usando-ja-segui-as-dicas-de-outro-post-erro-persiste-47332) o `Jersey` não funciona no servidor de aplicação *JBoss*, neste servidor só é possível utilizar o `Restlet`. Ao testar utilizando ele realmente obtive erros porém ao trocar para o *TomCat* ou *Glassfish* funcionou corretamente.

Comment: Qual o caminho pra import do ResourceConfig? Para mim, não aparece para importar.

Comment: `import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig`, verifiquei aqui e você não tem as dependências do jersey vou adicionar isto a minha resposta.

Comment: Adicionei as dependências e ainda não funciona. Tentei com "packages" e register. Eu coloquei um debug no construtor do JerseyConfig, porém, ele não chegou a passar lá. Preciso declarar algo no web.xml?

Comment: o método `MyApplication` em JerseyConfig é o método construtor, eu errei o nome entao deveria ser `public JerseyConfig() { }`

Comment: Sim, to ligado. Alterei para o correto, mas, mesmo assim não funciona...

Comment: tem certeza que a url `http://localhost:9090/resources/info` está correta? o servidor de aplicação não colocou um path com o nome da aplicação? algo como: `http://localhost:9090/myApplication/resources/info`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84280/discussion-between-lucas-duete-and-cristiano-bombazar).